# zsh: To understand spaces

Tags: bash, zsh

This is a one-line bash script by Ishmael Smyrnow to clear macOS icon cache:

```sh
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store; sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \; ; sleep 3;sudo touch /Applications/* ; killall Dock; killall Finder
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/ismyrnow/e92c6010cda9325b2d8811387a05f224)

I try to understand how to change it back to its multiple-line version. Here is what I have now:

```sh
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm -rfv {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rfv {} \;
sleep 3
sudo touch /Applications/*
killall Dock
killall Finder
```

I do understand in Ishmael's version semicolons are used for newlines and `\;` for literal semicolons. But what is the purpose to have a space between the two semicolons and after the asterisk? Is it safe to remove them?

```sh
 -exec rm -rfv {} \; ;
```

```sh
/Applications/* ;
```

Comment: Try for instance the command `echo ';';echo x`. You can see that it is not necessary to write a space in front of the semicolon which separates the statements. It's a question of aesthetics.

Comment: @user1934428: Or just `echo \;;echo x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces serve no purpose other than to improve readability. You can remove them if you wish.